# Remove a section of a website; web browser control. C#

Tags: c#, browser, pixel

Is there any way of removing a section of a website without altering the code?

For example, I create a webBrowser control in my Windows form and tell it to load stackoverflow.com. Would there be any way of removing the top 100 pixels from displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own html page with an iframe in it, load the site (e.g. stackoverflow) in the iframe and set the css margin-top property for the iframe to "-100px"

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I hadn't thought of this so I'll do it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The best I can come up with would be to have a panel overlap the top 100 pixels of the WebBrowser control.